# The function setFindTimeout does not work for me

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

I write functional tests for the web application on Intern.
I have a file in which I describe all the actions on the test, and also there is a test where these actions are called

for example:

there is an Action.ts file

in it functions which in the test are called sequentially

```
//1 
//open the registration window
openRegistration(): Command<void> {
    return Action.openRegistration(this.parent);
}

static openRegistration(command: Command<any>): Command<void> {
    return command
        // click on the authorization menu
        .setPageLoadTimeout (10000)
        .get(intern.args.url)
        .end()
}

//2
inputTextByCssSelector(selector: string, value: string): Command <void> {
    return Input.inputTextByCssSelector(this.parent, selector, value);
}

static inputTextByCssSelector(
    command: Command<any>,
    selector: string, 
    value: string
): Command<void> {
    return command
        .setFindTimeout(10000)
        .findByCssSelector(selector)
        .click()
        .type(value)
        .end()
        .end()
}
```

like this

```
.then(() => action.openRegistration())
.then(() => input.inputTextByCssSelector(
    "input [name = userName]", 
    intern.args.username
))
.then(() => input.inputTextByCssSelector(
    "input [name = password]", 
    intern.args.password
))
```

But when I run the test, it drops.

If I set an explicit delay at the end of openRegistration for example like this

```
openRegistration(): Command<void> {
    return Action.openRegistration(this.parent);
}

static openRegistration(command: Command<any>): Command<void> {
    return command
        .setPageLoadTimeout(10000)
        .get(intern.args.url)
        .sleep(7000)
        .end()
}
```

then everything works

Why does not work `setFindTimeout(10000)` in `inputTextByCssSelector`, but with `sleep(7000)` in `openRegistration` works

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "it drops"? Is the test throwing a timeout error?

One potential issue is component visibility. Is there some delay between when the page has loaded and the elements you're trying to interact with become visible (like, a JS fade in animation)? The `findBy` commands return the first found element, but that element may not be visible. If it's not visible, Intern can't interact with it, and a command like `type` will fail. To wait until the element is visible, use `findDisplayedByCssSelector`.

Note that spacing is important in CSS selectors. The selector `"input [name = userName]"` is actually looking for an element with attribute `name=userName` contained within an `input` element. Assuming the actual intention is to select an input with a particular name attribute, it should be formatted as `'input[name="userName"]'`.

Also note that `end()` commands are only needed after `find` commands, and aren't typically needed at the end of command chains in helper commands (things started from `this.parent`). So, for example, there's no need for an `end` after the `get` in `openRegistration`, and at most one `end` would be needed in `inputTextByCssSelector` (for the `findByCssSelector` command).

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar to this (just not using TypeScript) when I first started learning how to use intern and hit some similar issues to what you're having.

The issue for me was that the `Promise` chain wasn't being maintained correctly as the test executed. You should try making a subtle change to your code as follows in order to increase the consistency of the `Promise` chain.

So just for example, your test script is like this before we start:

```
return this.remote
    .then(() => action.openRegistration())
    .then(() => input.inputTextByCssSelector("input[name = userName]", intern.args.username))
    .then(() => input.inputTextByCssSelector("input[name = password]", intern.args.password))
```

The first thing you need to do is remove those arrow functions. I had several issues when using arrow functions, namely the `this.remote` leadfoot/Session was not passed around consistently between methods when I did this.

So your first `.then()` statement invokes a method called `openRegistration()`, right? Edit your method to, instead, return a `function` which executes the steps you are looking for:

```
static openRegistration(): Command<void> {
    return function () {
        return this.parent
            .setPageLoadTimeout (10000)
            .get(intern.args.url)
            .end()
   };
}
```

So now your test script will look something like this (and assuming you repeat this pattern for all methods you are calling):

```
return this.remote
    .then(action.openRegistration())
    .then(input.inputTextByCssSelector("input[name = userName]", intern.args.username))
    .then(input.inputTextByCssSelector("input[name = password]", intern.args.password))
```

This should resolve your problem.